# Шрифт подключен правильно, но не работает. В чем причина?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты, кириллица

На сайте подключен шрифт Laverna Deco - [страница с шрифтом](http://dminkeif.beget.tech)
Надпись "Людмила Саабурова" и остальные заголовки.

Подключен с помощью @font-face, пути правильные, кириллическое начертание есть, в фотошопе отображается, а на сайте нет.

В чём причина?

Comment: Кто сказал, что правильно подключен?

Comment: может woff и woff2?

Comment: Консоль ошибок не показывает, шрифт по прямой ссылке открывается

Comment: ttf с кириллицей, дальше сгенерировал woff и т.д.

Comment: как вы проверяете поддержку кириллицы?

Comment: @soledar10 хороший вопрос мне самому интересно

Comment: В фотошопе кириллица есть. И если в винду подключить этот шрифт, тогда и на сайте отображается

Comment: скорее всего шрифт содержит какую-то ошибку. Скачал шрифт - https://www.fonts-online.ru/font/Laverna-Deco. Прогнал через https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. Все работает

Comment: Нашел причину, я не выбрал кириллицу в генераторе

Comment: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Subsetting --> Custom Subsetting... --> Language --> Cyrillic

Comment: У меня в ttf была кириллица в woff и т.д. не было